# c++ game exe stopped working, lot of class. Working in visual c++

Tags: c++, structure, exe, sfml, code-cleanup

Hi it's been some weeks Im developping a game for a contest. (I am familiar with coding a little, but not a lot).

I'm writing the game with visual c++. When I run it in release mode on Visual c++, it runs ok, but when I try from the .exe, a window pops-up and say "****.exe has stopped working". I know what does the error but I don't know how to fix it. The error pops-up because there is a lot of vectors, If I delete some vectors resizing from the program the game runs, it can be anyting, a wall, a box vector, it doesn't matter. But I find it really strange because when I look up in the task manager the games only takes up 20,000K of Memory.

So in conclusion, if I delete some vectors from the game, the game exe runs, if not, it will only run in visual c++. What should I do? I'm really lost.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

OK if I resize only four vector list, the .exe will run, but if I resize more than 4, the exe will give an error, but the visual c++ instance still runs.

```
class Level
{

public:

    int LevelWidth;
    MapElements::Background Background;

    //OBJETS SUR MAP
    Array<MapElements::Ground> Grounds;
    Array<MapElements::Wall> Walls;
    Array<MapElements::Platform> Platforms;
    Array<MapElements::Box> Boxs;

    //ENNEMIS et JOUEUR
    Array<Gameplay::Droite> Droites;
    Array<Gameplay::Cercle> Cercles;
    Gameplay::Player Player;
};
```

this works:

```
 void Level::InitializeMap(int MaxGround, int MaxWall, int MaxPlatforms, int MaxBox)
 {
     Grounds.Element.resize(MaxGround);
     Walls.Element.resize(MaxWall);
     Platforms.Element.resize(MaxPlatforms);
     Boxs.Element.resize(MaxBox);
 }
```

this doesn't:

```
 void Level::InitializeMap(int MaxGround, int MaxWall, int MaxPlatforms, int MaxBox, int      MaxCercles)
{
    Grounds.Element.resize(MaxGround);
    Walls.Element.resize(MaxWall);
    Platforms.Element.resize(MaxPlatforms);
    Boxs.Element.resize(MaxBox);
    Cercles.Element.resize(MaxCercles);
}
```

the Array class:

```
template <typename T> class Array
{
public:
    std::vector<T> Element;
    Array();

};
template <typename T> Array<T>::Array()
{
}
```

The resizing works if I only have 4 vector.resize(), and it can be any of the variables (wall, box, etc), what is the source of the error?

Comment: How are you compiling the exe?  16-bit mode?  There is no small limit on number of classes unless you are building in some limited way.

Comment: My guess would be there is a file required at runtime which is available at runtime when running from within visual studio, but not when you run the exe. Are all the resources that the game requires in the same directory as the executable?

Comment: Wow why down votes? No there isn`t any missing files, I know there isn`t limits for classes but I will look at the compiling.

Comment: If some people could vote up this, its a serious question! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrong about what's causing that error. On windows `*.exe has stopped working`. generally means that your application has [segmentation faulted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segfault).

This can be caused by any read or write out of the memory bounds, which generally means you messed up with a `free()`/`delete`, a `malloc()`/`new`, or a `NULL` somewhere, but with more code, or without further explanation, I cannot diagnose further.

Comment: Thanks! I didn`t use any of these, so I messed up a lot of things... I found out an article about how to use them so I`ll try it out. But is it normal it runs ok in Visual c++ and not in the exe? It`s still the same program right? What`s the difference between the two of them?

Answer (score 0):

When you run your game in vc, the working directory is defaulted to the project directory if you hadn't changed it.

When you run it from the .exe, the working directory is the directory where the .exe lies in.

So maybe you could check if your game relies on something which can't be located correctly when you run it directly.

Comment: I`m pretty sure all the Dlls and graphics are there. Do my problem have a relation with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763739/problem-retuning-a-vector-from-a-c-dll-to-another-c-exe

Comment: @user1236892, is it possible that your program over-used the stack and caused a stack overflow? The default stack size should be 1MB, maybe the reserved stack size is larger when the program is runned in ide?

Answer (score 0):

You are fundamentally using Vector wrongly.  You're immediately sizing them to the max possible size they could be instead of letting them resize accordingly.  You are probably blowing out all of your available memory.

It would probably be better to do this:

```
class Level
{

public:

    int LevelWidth;
    MapElements::Background Background;

    //OBJETS SUR MAP
    MapElements::Ground Grounds[MAXGROUNDS];
    MapElements::Wall Walls[MAXWALLS];
    MapElements::Platform Platforms[MAXPLATFORMS];
    MapElements::Box Boxs[MAXBOXES];

    //ENNEMIS et JOUEUR
    Array<Gameplay::Droite> Droites;
    Array<Gameplay::Cercle> Cercles;
    Gameplay::Player Player;
};
```

And rely on the allocation of Level to initialize your level's memory.

Now.  I don't know what MaxCercles is.  But you need to make certain you aren't using up too much memory (aka if they are all MAXINTS you are in a little bit of trouble depending on how big each class is).

If you are going to use vectors just set them to a default middle ground size (like 100 or something) and let them resize themselves based on what you add.